# How to infer default generic parameter from a function type?

Tags: typescript

How could I extract the function's default type parameter to get something like this statement to compile?

```js
const fails: string = "" as ReturnType<<T = string>() => T>;
```

Comment: why should the return type of `func` be `string`? `func` is a generic function. `T` is not constrained to be any particular type. All it has is a default type of `string` but it could be anything so TypeScript infers the return type as `unknown`.

Comment: Those two formulations are unrelated.  In the former, you have a generic *type* named `func<T>` which evaluates to a specific (non-generic) function type when you plug in `T`.  When you refer to it as just `func`, you are implicitly specifying `T` with its default, so it's `func<string>`, and the return type of that is `string`.  In the latter you have a method named `func` whose type is a specific (non-generic) type corresponding to a generic function, whose type parameter `T` is only specified when you call it. Thus the return type of `Container["func"]` can be *anything*, hence `unknown`

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with this question.  It seems to argue from a flawed premise; I'd suggest removing the whole first part with "correctly infers" because it's doing something completely different, and just ask the part about `Container`, which you can refactor succinctly to "why is `ReturnType<<T = string>()=>T>` evaluating to `unknown` instead of `string`?"

Comment: Or maybe you really do want to know why generic types evaluating to specific functions are different from specific types evaluating to generic functions, in which case I'd suggest removing the stuff about default parameters and just ask about that difference.  Which one is your primary question, and how can we improve this to get to good SO question/answer pair?

Comment: @jcalz thank you for your input. I tried narrowing the question. Could you please take a look again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReturnType<<T = string>() => T>` is `unknown` and not `string`:

```
type F = <T = string>() => T;

type X = ReturnType<F>;
// type X = unknown
```

According to [microsoft/TypeScript#42064](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42064#issuecomment-750495482),

> the default only applies during a direct call when no inference candidates are present

which means that a [generic parameter default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) like `string` for `T` only matters if you directly call a function of type `<T = string>() => T` and if normal type inference fails.  But `ReturnType<F>` doesn't actually call a function, it just inspects the type of `F` and infers its return type.  Since `T` can be literally anything, then the compiler has no idea what it will actually be.  It replaces `T` with its (implicit) constraint, [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown).

As far as I know there's no way to get the default out of a generic function type without calling a function of that type.  [Conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) doesn't work:

```
type Y = F extends <T = infer U>(...args: any) => any ? U : never;
// type Y = unknown
```

You could *pretend* to call a function of that type, but it's obnoxious. Something like:

```
let r;
if (false as true) {
  // won't actually happen but the compiler doesn't know this 
  const f = null! as F;
  r = f();
} else {
  r = null!
}
type Z = typeof r; // string
```

Depending on your use case you *might* get away with something like that, but for most purposes I'd say that a generic default is nearly unobservable in the type system.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYlC8UA8AVBUDOwBOBLAdgOYB8AFAJQLFQoDcAsAFBOiRQAa6AShMAK7Z8KcBCQxiDRgHopUVtE6I++ANb4A9gHd8TFiKgBNdHAgAPYBHwATDMjSICAMwjYoAVTIA6bwENshDAAuKB98EEp4alCQKAB+dyhg-AgANxdJGTl9IyVVDW1dRgAbXihsSVxHKFJHHyKMaB9bHD4ISgBvJigoTM11fAByYBCAY346opiACx8wSHwoACM+YeAp6BH1AFswXBLXK3UIDEHhtS05KdxbLqhN-CwoKsR8PiKigEIQ2xhJbtdEI4KJIAL5QCD1aCdRj-dCvd4fJggvRsABa6Hk6iq5R6siweCIhSAA)

Comment: Would support for empty instantiation expressions help then?

Comment: *Empty* instantiation expressions like `f<>`?  Possibly, but you'd still have to pretend to have a value of the function type without having to pretend to *call* it.  Doesn't seem like a huge win, unfortunately.

Comment: Does that mean there's also no way to use instantiation expressions on a member of another type?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I re-read your comments and answer to realize why not. Thank you so much!